# Can we use Robot Framework reporting mechanism in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

In Robot Framework, a `Log.html` file is generated, which contains details about the test suite, in an appropriate format and detail. Along with the HTML file, an `Output.xml` file is also generated.

Selenium also creates an `.xml` file, which is generated after executing the test suite.

How can I use the Selenium XML files as a "base", and then generate HTML files, similar to Robot Framework?

Comment: Can you  elaborate on how you generate those selenium xml files and their format?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you are generating "selenium .xml files", but if they are in the same format as the robot files then you can generate a robot report using [rebot](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-robot-and-rebot-scripts).

```
$ rebot some_file.xml
```

However, I doubt that any tool other than robot framework itself generates .xml files in the proper format for rebot to process.